# List all attributes in a model (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a blog app and I'm trying to get all posts to be listed on the index/homepage.

Here's my BlogPost model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        return f"{self.text[:50]}..."
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import BlogPost

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    body = BlogPost.objects.values('text')
    context = {'posts': posts, 'body':body}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)
```

and my index.html:

```
<p> Blog </p>

<p> Here's some articles I've written: </p>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1> {{post}} </h1>
        <p> {{body}} </p>
    {%empty%}
        <li> Sacrebleu! Where is me posts? </li>
    {%endfor%}
```

The issue is how it's being displayed:

```
Blog

Here's some articles I've written:

Favorite things:
<QuerySet [{'text': "blah blah blah"}, {'text': "lorem ipsum"}]>

This is a test:
<QuerySet [{'text': "blah blah blah"}, {'text': "lorem ipsum"}]>
```

Instead, I'd like for it to display as:

```
Blog

Here's some articles I've written:

Favorite things:
blah blah blah 

This is a test:
lorem ipsum
```

I feel like it has something to do with the id attribute, but I really can't point it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the title and text for the blog post object in the html for loop.

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    posts = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'posts': posts}
    return render(request, 'blogs/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```html
<p> Blog </p>

<p> Here's some articles I've written: </p>

{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p> Sacrebleu! Where is me posts? </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Truly a class act! Thanks! I know this must've been an easy fix but your quick response is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the parts of the post you want in the for loop, like this:

```
<p> Blog </p>

<p> Here's some articles I've written: </p>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1> {{post.title}} </h1>
        <p> {{post.body}} </p>
    {%endfor%}
```